# Opening POSTed file with PIL Image

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, webob

Using WSGI, webob and PIL, I'm trying to use `Image.open()` on a file directly from the request.  However, `Image.open()` always throws the exception "cannot identify image file".  The image is the only field, no other POST or GET variables are used.  The file is coming from a standard HTML upload form with enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
import Image, ImageFile
from webob import Request

def application(environ, start_response):
    req = Request(environ)
    req.make_body_seekable() 
    im = Image.open(req.body_file) # "Cannot identify image file"
    im.save('testfileio.png','PNG')
```

My guess is I'm not loading in the uploaded image data correctly, but am not sure what the right way to do it would be.

Comment: When you say it's “POSTed”, do you mean you're using a special tool to POST a request with body `Content-Type: image/png`? Or do you just mean you've got a browser and a `multipart/form-data` form with only one field, an `<input type="file">`? If the latter then you still need to parse the form in the usual way to get the file upload field out of it.

Comment: It's the latter, this is a standard file upload form in HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not famaliar with webob, but my guess is that body_file contains the contents of the entire post and not just your image.  The [docs](http://pythonpaste.org/webob/reference.html#request-body) seem to confirm this.

What's in req.POST['nameOfFileControl']?  Does that have a file handle?  That is going to be the file handle that Image.open needs.